# how to consume data from AMQ using WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, amq, wso2-esb

Hi I have created a queue which pushes data to queue but unable to get any response. It gives response as "WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-5 Socket Timeout". And also I want to fetch messages from that queue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add more details on what you have tried out

Comment: Added just destination of the queue and content type to be displayed. Can you tell me how to fetch data from queue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB supports AMQP via RabbitMQ transport [1]. You can configure a consumer for the queue as in [2]. Explain in more detail what you have tried out so far, to help with the problem you are facing.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/ESB+as+a+RabbitMQ+Message+Consumer

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maheeka. My proxy is to push the data to a queue. and I need to fetch the data one by one. i am using AMQ to store my data. I have enabled TransportReceiver and sender. When I referred to docs they are using a service which are preconfigured creating .aar file (SimpleStockQuote). Can you tell me how to create a response and how to read the message one by one from queue.